# Can I use property of owned type in alternate key?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I want to support such sql in EF:

```
create table prepare(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    target_id int not null,
    key_user_id int not null,
    key_date date not null,

    primary key(id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ak__prepare
    ON prepare (
        target_id,
        key_user_id,
        key_date
    );
```

My models:

```
public sealed class Prepare
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Uniq
    public int TargetId { get; set; }
    public Key Key { get; set; }    
    // End uniq
}

public class Key {
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

When I configure it like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Prepare>()
    .OwnsOne(z => z.Key)
    .HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.TargetId, c.Key.UserId, c.Key.Date });
```

EF said

The properties expression 'c => new <>f__AnonymousType32`4(TargetId = c.TargetId, UserId = c.Key.UserId, Date = c.Key.Date)' is not valid. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

When I configure it like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Prepare>()
    .OwnsOne(z => z.Key)
    .HasAlternateKey(c => new { c.TargetId, c.Key });
```

EF said

''Key' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Prepare' because it is configured as a navigation.'

So the only way - forget about owned types?